# ReferenceError: player1 is not defined

Tags: javascript

Итак, уважаемые знатоки, вопрос состоит в следующем:
У меня есть две кнопки в HTML: одна вызывает функцию new1, а другая - new2.
Также у меня есть JS:

```
var id = 1;
var name = "Имя";
var lpos = 50;
var bpos = 50;
var kolvo = 0;

function new1() {
  var player1 = new Object() //создаем игрока 1
  player1.id = 1; //присваиваем свойства
  player1.name = name; //устанавливаем имя
  player1.status = 1; //живой-1 мертвый-0
  player1.location = "Летний лес"; //определяем локацию
  player1.lpos = lpos; //определяем местоположение
  player1.bpos = bpos; //определяем местоположение
  alert("Первый игрок создан");
}

function new2() {
  var player2 = new Object() //создаем игрока 2
  player2.id = 2; //присваиваем свойства
  player2.name = name; //устанавливаем имя
  player2.status = 1; //живой-1 мертвый-0
  player2.location = "Летний лес"; //определяем локацию
  player2.lpos = lpos; //определяем местоположение
  player2.bpos = bpos; //определяем местоположение
  alert("Второй игрок создан");
}

document.onkeypress = function checkKeycode(event) {
  var keycode; //keycode
  var keyChar; //keychar
  if (!event) var event = window.event;
  if (event.keyCode) keycode = event.keyCode;
  else if (event.which) keycode = event.which;
  keyChar = String.fromCharCode(keycode);

  if (id == player1.id) {
    if (keyChar == "'") { // если кнопка влево
      player1.lpos = player1.lpos + 5;
      alert("player1 прошли вперед");
    }
    if (keyChar == "&") { // если кнопка вверх
      alert("player1 прыгнули"); //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!прыжок пока не готов!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
    if (keyChar == "%") { // если кнопка вправо
      player1.lpos = player1.lpos - 5;
      alert("player1 прошли назад");
    }
  }
  if (id == player2.id) {
    if (keyChar == "'") { // если кнопка влево
      player2.lpos = player2.lpos + 5;
      alert("player2 прошли вперед");
    }
    if (keyChar == "&") { // если кнопка вверх
      alert("player2 прыгнули"); //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!прыжок пока не готов!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
    if (keyChar == "%") { // если кнопка вправо
      player2.lpos = player2.lpos - 5;
      alert("player2 прошли назад");
    }
  }

}
```

При нажатии на первую кнопку должен создаваться объект player1, что, собственно говоря, и происходит.

При нажатии кнопки "влево" должен выскакивать мэссэндж с именем игрока и его действием, но после нажатия кнопки "влево" консоль выдает следующие нехорошие слова:

> ReferenceError: player1 is not defined

Ну а теперь самый важный вопрос: что не так?

P.S. Пока не стал отдельно создавать плееров, все работало на ура.

Answer (score 2):

Вы создали функции new1 и new2, чтобы они заработали, нужно их вызвать, добавьте в код:

```
new1();
new2();
```

и всё должно заработать, только не добавляйте внутрь `document.onkeypress`.

Answer (score 2):

У вас `player1` в `new1()` создаётся, а `player2` в `new2()`. Поэтому при обращении к ним в `document.onkeypress = function checkKeycode(event) {...}` выскакивает ошибка.

Объявите эти переменный перед методами.

```
var id = 1;
var name = "Имя";
var lpos = 50;
var bpos = 50;
var kolvo = 0;
var player1 = new Object();
var player2 = new Object();

function new1() {
[...]
}

// и т.д.
```